# What to do with roof leaking down the end gable?

Tags: roof, leak

I'm renting a house in the north of England. Currently we have a storm, and my roof is leaking. There's not too much water in my upstairs rooms yet. I read about this online, and it says that while the storm is going the only thing to do is put buckets out. I had a look in the roof, and all of the water is coming in along the wall so it's not possible to put buckets under it. I've moved my stuff away from this wall so it doesn't get wet.

So I have two questions:

1. Looks like the storm is set to go for a good eight or more hours still. Is there some way to contain the water dripping down the wall, similarly to putting a bucket underneath a drip? The amount of water in my bedroom is rapidly increasing unfortunately.
2. Based on the picture, what should I say to my landlord needs to be done to fix the roof?

(My experience is that if I say to him 'the roof was leaking' he says, 'oh it's probably fine', but if I say 'the roof was leaking because of X reason, here's a picture and you need to get someone in to do Y to fix it', then he takes it more seriously. )

[image: My leaky attic]

Comment: Would it be possible to drape a waterproof tarpaulin over the roof and side of house where the leak is occurring? This would help prevent some of the water intrusion until repairs could be made.

Comment: @Glen Yates Are you suggesting to climb up onto the roof now during the storm? I think I might have to leave doing that one. Or do you mean inside the attic?

Comment: Yes, outside, inside the attic won't do much good. I have hastily climbed onto a roof in the rain to put a tarp over a leaking chimney, but I do understand the hesitancy. As you are in the north of the UK, it is probably a cold rain right now; and as you are renting, it is not your own house -- these two details would probably sway me not to get on the roof either.

Comment: @Glen Yates, yep cold rain and snow with 40mph wind. Thanks for your advice anyway

Comment: Thing is, you'll probably not find the leak from the inside. That looks like a chimney breast at the end, in which case, suspect the flashing. A lot of houses of that age used cement filler at 45° to save on lead. It pulls away after a time. As far as the landlord's concerned, tell him water is pi\*\*ing down the walls & he needs to fix it *now*. Don't take no for an answer. He's still going to have to deal with the consequences of it getting wet inside - dehumidifiers, re-decorating… the quicker he does it the cheaper it will be.